# How to set up domain name and attach it to my server IP address (Apache2)

Tags: apache, dns

I have a vps in **IONOS** with ubuntu 18.04.

I have followed [this tuto](https://www.maketecheasier.com/name-based-virtualhost-apache/) to configure apache , and my new website.

Right now , the website **work only with ip** address but not with domain name.

This is www.mydomainname.com.conf under  **/etc/apache2/sites-available**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@mydomainname.com
ServerName  www.mydomainname.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.mydomainname.com
<Directory /var/www/html/www.mydomainname.com/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my the config under **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1       localhost
82.***.***.**   www.mydomainname.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

That's all

Comment: You need to follow this https://www.ionos.com/help/domains/configuring-your-ip-address/change-a-domains-ip-address-a-record/ and cofigure A record for www.mydomainname.com pointing to 82.165.112.22

Comment: Thank you very much